# How to rename a postgres table only if the target table name does not exist

Tags: postgresql

I want to rename a table as part of a migration, but only if the table has not been renamed already. I'm currently running:

```sql
ALTER TABLE IF EXISTS old_name RENAME TO new_name
```

however, if `new_name` already exists it will still run. Is there a way to run this statement if and only if `new_name` does not exist?

Answer (score 7):

You could always write an anonymous code block (or also a user defined function/procedure) similar to:

```
DO $$
BEGIN
    IF NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM pg_tables WHERE tablename = 'z') THEN  
        EXECUTE 'ALTER TABLE a RENAME TO z';
    END IF;
END$$;
```

As far as I know you cannot specify it with the ALTER TABLE command directly.

Comment: You don't need dynamic SQL, you can use the `ALTER TABLE` "as is"

Answer (score -1):

Since there is no proper answer, you can do it with

```
ALTER TABLE IF EXISTS <table_name> RENAME TO <new_table>;
```